# SVG line animation first erasing and then drawing

Tags: html, css, svg

I want my animation to work as https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/Hjyio like drawing the image from scratch. But what my animation is doing that first it's erasing the picture and then drawing again.

```css
path {
  fill: #FFF;
  stroke: #000;
  animation: my_animation 3s linear forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 400;
}

@keyframes my_animation {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0; 
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 400;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 89.999 89.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 89.999 89.999;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px">
  <g>
    <path d="M89.551,24.201c-5.029,28.863-33.127,53.301-41.577,58.883c-8.454,5.582-16.163-2.236-18.96-8.148   c-3.201-6.738-12.793-43.285-15.307-46.311C11.195,25.596,3.656,31.65,3.656,31.65L0,26.768c0,0,15.307-18.623,26.957-20.951   c12.35-2.469,12.332,19.318,15.301,31.416c2.873,11.701,4.807,18.398,7.312,18.398c2.514,0,7.311-6.525,12.562-16.531   c5.264-10.016-0.225-18.857-10.505-12.568C55.738,1.395,94.578-4.65,89.551,24.201z" fill="#ff0043"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Any help or suggestion so it starts to draw only instead of first erasing it also how to fill it with colour at last ?

Comment: You tried swapping the values?

Comment: yes made it worse

Comment: Sorry? Show us what you tried then.

Comment: its will then first make the image then erase it :p @Kaiido

Comment: got it in the below answer thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the starting *keyframe* to start with `stroke-dashoffset: 400` or simply add it to the `path` rules, and use a separate `animation` for *filling*:

```css
path {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #000;
  animation: my_animation 3s linear forwards, filling .5s linear 3s forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 400; /* need to ... */
  stroke-dashoffset: 400; /* ... match */
}

@keyframes my_animation {
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}

@keyframes filling {
  to {fill: #000}
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 89.999 89.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 89.999 89.999;" xml:space="preserve" width="512px" height="512px">
  <g>
    <path d="M89.551,24.201c-5.029,28.863-33.127,53.301-41.577,58.883c-8.454,5.582-16.163-2.236-18.96-8.148   c-3.201-6.738-12.793-43.285-15.307-46.311C11.195,25.596,3.656,31.65,3.656,31.65L0,26.768c0,0,15.307-18.623,26.957-20.951   c12.35-2.469,12.332,19.318,15.301,31.416c2.873,11.701,4.807,18.398,7.312,18.398c2.514,0,7.311-6.525,12.562-16.531   c5.264-10.016-0.225-18.857-10.505-12.568C55.738,1.395,94.578-4.65,89.551,24.201z" fill="#ff0043"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```